# Unable to get WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY, WP_DEBUG_LOG to work

Tags: plugins, errors, debug

I've got the proper debugging constants defined in wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

But they're not doing a darn thing. When I output something to the log file from my plugin (even without testing for `WP_DEBUG === true`) like this nothing happens on-screen and there's no debug.log to be found either:

```
error_log('test!');
```

I'm sure that part of the code in the plug is being executed. What gives? I'm using WP 3.6.1. Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me. This has to have something to do with your server environment. How much control of the server do you have? Can you access the actual server logs?

Comment: I found out that when using the MAMP Pro environment, the errors are going to the MAMP Apache error log. So I can see the errors there. However I'm still not sure why the errors aren't being displayed on-screen (which they should be since I set WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY to true). Does anyone know why I don't see the errors on-screen?

Comment: If in case your WordPress installation have any bug, try Re-Installing WordPress Core from `/wp-admin/update-core.php`

Comment: Create an empty `wp-content/debug.log` file, and then make sure the web service (Apache) has [write permissions](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/background/file-permissions) to that file. Easiest way is to allow everyone read/write access -- `chmod wp-content/debug.log 666`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the below code worked for me. You should enter it in wp-config.php and above "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */":

```
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Thank you @Buttered_Toast. I updated my answer.